# how to get primary and foreign key in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get know what are the primary and foreign keys in any table.

*I tried this:*

```sql
SELECT K.COLUMN_NAME FROM  

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T 

JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE K

ON K.CONSTRAINT_NAME=T.CONSTRAINT_NAME  

WHERE  K.TABLE_NAME=‘YOUR-TABLE-NAME’  

AND K.TABLE_SCHEMA=‘YOUR-DATABASE_NAME’

AND T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE=’PRIMARY KEY’ LIMIT 1;
```

and got this error

> Table name "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.

Answer (score 2):

Google BigQuery doesn't have primary key or foreign key constraints, which is why you can't find them.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) is the INFORMATION_SCHEMA reference documentation, which shows the information that *is* available.

Answer (score 1):

You can now add PK & FK to BQ.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_constraint_statement

To fetch information about them:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-constraint-column-usage

```
SELECT *
FROM <PROJECT_ID>.<DATASET>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE;
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-key-column-usage

```
SELECT *
FROM PROJECT_ID.DATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE;
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-constraints

```
SELECT *
FROM PROJECT_ID.DATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS;
```